# how to improve the efficiency?

Tags: java, multithreading, performance, biginteger

As a school assingment I have a really big `for` (it goes from 1 to a 13 digits number) with a few BigInteger operations inside. To reduce the loop I can skip all the even numbers and to avoid unnecessary BigInteger operations I can check for multiples of 3, 5, 7 and 11. Here is an exemple:

```
for(long i = min; i < max; i += 2){    
    if( i%3 != 0 && i%5 != 0 && i%7 != 0 && i%11 != 0){
        BigInteger aux = new BigInteger(Long.toString(i));
        BigInteger[] aux2 = k.divideAndRemainder(aux);
        if(aux2[1].longValueExact() == 0){
            list.add(aux);
            list.add(aux2[0]);
    }
}
```

Now, this loop would take months to finish, so I thought of breaking the `for` in multiple threads, each one covering a window of the original 13-digits-number.

My first question is: with a i7-3770 processor, how many threads could I have to be as fast as efficiently possible?

edit: the assingment is to otimize a problem that requires a lot of CPU. In this case, to find all divisors of a 23 digits number (the "k" in `k.divideAndRemainder(aux)`), thats why I'm using BigIntegers. The 13 digits number used by the `for` is the root of k.

Comment: Are you sure that the school assignment is about doing a lot of CPU burning instead of coming up with some clever algorithm to *avoid* the CPU burn?

Comment: If it will take months to finish, the language choice is not your main concern: the algorithm is the bottleneck.

Comment: the first can be answered by yourself. Spawn as many threads as the application can handle. Then check the log and you know how many you could use. 
What´s the purpose of this program? it might be that you´re simply having an inefficent implementaiton.

Comment: If you want to avoid having your question closed, edit out that last question about Java, and change the title asap. The programming language is definitely not a concern here.

Comment: Sounds like an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/286538). You really should explain what the school assignment is. Are you trying to find all the divisors of a large number? Trying to see if a number is prime?

Comment: I edited my post. I will try some of the suggestions given so far.

Answer (score 2):

- Java is fine for multithreading. BigInteger is not exactly performant, but that's not the problem.
- On that processor, up to 8 threads can utilize the cores completely. I doubt you run a custom OS that allows you to cede full CPU control to an application, so you want to keep at least 1 logical core for the OS and associated services, as well as 1 for Java misc threads.
- If your program takes months to complete on a single thread, then using 4 threads **efficiently** will make it take weeks to complete. While that's a big speedup, I don't think that's quite enough for you, is it?
- This is a school assignment, as you've said yourself. Just like with Project Euler, there are ways to do it, and there are ways to do it right. The first ones take days of computing on powerful machines after 10 minutes programming, the latter ones take days of thinking and seconds of computing. Your problem is not the hardware or language, it's the algorithm.

---

Now for the actual stuff that you can do better. From obvious to less so.

- `BigInteger aux = new BigInteger(Long.toString(i));` Are you mad? Why would you convert a `long` to a `String` and then parse it back to a number?! This is stupid slow. Just use `BigInteger.valueOf(long val)`.
- `BigInteger` is slower than primitives. Why do you need it if your values (up to 13 digits, as you've said yourself) fit comfortably in a `long`? If the only reason is the `divideAndRemainder` method - write one yourself! It's going to be 2 lines of code...
- You seem to be looking for divisors of a particular number. (The filtering of multiples of 3,5,7,11 makes me think you're looking for prime ones and will do some filtering later) There is a number of speedups for such algorithms, main one being (and it's not clear whether you're using it) is making the maximum checked number the square root of the target, rather than the number itself, half of it, or whatever arbitrary bound people make up. Other ones can be found in the [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes) or [more complex wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_factorization)

Comment: I edited my post. I will try some of the suggestions given so far.